# Accept Terms and Conditions on JS webpage using R to Scrape (rvest)

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I have another nube question regarding webscraping. I am using Rvest to try to scrape some data from a police report website. I have been looking around but I can't seem to find a way to bypass the "accept the terms and conditions" of the site "I agree" button.  How can I submit a "I agree" in order to get to the website?

website=http://www.wspdp2c.org/Summary_Disclaimer.aspx

```
require(httr)
require(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rvest)

wspd.url<- "http://www.wspdp2c.org/Summary_Disclaimer.aspx"

wspd.session<-html_session(wspd.url)
wspd.form<-html_form(read_html(wspd.session))
wspd.form
```

R ouput:

```
> wspd.form
[[1]]
<form> 'Form1' (POST ./Summary_Disclaimer.aspx)
  <input hidden> '_popupBlockerExists': true
  <input hidden> '__VIEWSTATE': /wEPDwUKLTUwMDM5Nzk4OA9....
  <input hidden> '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': 27903AD3
  <input hidden> '__EVENTVALIDATION': /wEdAAky7XCY2Cjbe0DHcJ....
  <select> 'ctl00$MasterPage$DDLSiteMap1$ddlQuickLinks' [1/7]
  <input submit> 'ctl00$MasterPage$mainContent$CenterColumnContent$btnContinue': I Agree
```

Comment: It's a sharepoint-driven site. just use RSelenium or seleniumPipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to work out how to get selenium running on your system and how to get the `remoteDr(...)` call going. After that, this should help get you started:

```
library(seleniumPipes)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

remDr  <- remoteDr(...)

remDr %>% go("http://www.wspdp2c.org/Summary_Disclaimer.aspx")

submit <- remDr %>% findElement("xpath", ".//input[@type='submit']")
submit %>% elementClick()

from_date <- remDr %>% findElement("xpath", ".//input[@name='MasterPage$mainContent$txtDateFrom2']")
from_date %>% elementClear()
from_date %>% elementSendKeys("12/22/2016")
to_date %>% elementSendKeys("12/23/2016", selKeys$escape) # esc clears the popup calednar

to_date <- remDr %>% findElement("xpath", ".//input[@name='MasterPage$mainContent$txtDateTo2']")
to_date %>% elementClear()
to_date %>% elementSendKeys("12/23/2016", selKeys$escape)

search <- remDr %>% findElement("class name", "ui-icon-search")
search %>% elementClick()

remDr %>% getPageSource() -> pg
html_nodes(pg, "table.DataGridText") -> tab

html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[2]")[1:9] %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  as.POSIXct(format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") -> occurred

html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[3]")[1:9] %>% 
  html_text() -> incident_or_arrest

html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[4]")[1:9] %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  stri_trim_both() -> case_or_arrestee

stri_match_all_regex(case_or_arrestee,
                     paste0(c("Case #: ([[:digit:]]+)",
                       "Primary Offense: ([[:print:]]+)",
                       "Arrestee: ([[:print:]]+)",
                       "Charge: ([[:print:]]+)"), collapse="|")) %>% 
  map(~apply(.[,2:5], 1, discard, is.na)) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    x <- as.list(x)
    if (stri_detect_regex(x[[1]], "[[:alpha:]]")) {
      setNames(x, c("arrestee", "charge"))
    } else {
      setNames(x, c("case_number", "primary_offense"))
    }
  }) -> case_or_arrestee

html_nodes(tab, xpath=".//td[5]")[1:9] %>% 
  html_text() -> location

data_frame(occurred, incident_or_arrest, location) %>% 
  bind_cols(case_or_arrestee) %>% 
  glimpse()
## Observations: 9
## Variables: 7
## $ occurred           <dttm> 2016-12-22 00:00:00, 2016-12-22 00:00:00, 2016-12-22 00:0...
## $ incident_or_arrest <chr> "Incident", "Incident", "Arrest", "Incident", "Incident", ...
## $ location           <chr> "2600-BLK    TODDLER PLACE DR", "300-BLK    ALSPAUGH DR", ...
## $ case_number        <chr> "1667276", "1667273", NA, "1667249", "1667248", NA, NA, "1...
## $ primary_offense    <chr> "BREAKING & ENTERING WITH FORCE", "MALICIOUS INJURY TO PRO...
## $ arrestee           <chr> NA, NA, "THOMAS, KERRY MARTIN", NA, NA, "LOZANO, MIGUEL AR...
## $ charge             <chr> NA, NA, "PANHANDLING W/ NO PRIVLEDGE LICENSE", NA, NA, "AN...
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment:  Once you've fully tested it, ticking the answer checkmark helps others grok that it's a solution